# how can we print (n +nn +nnn) using println for this code?

Tags: java, println

```java
int n; 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input number: ");
n = in .nextInt();
System.out.println(n " + " nn ); //this is not working
```

how can i print using println

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Comment: That's an syntax error , use some ide to easily find errors.
your code should be like this System.out.println("n "+ n );

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me, for example for **n = 1**, what should be the output? please confirm. Whether it should be **1 + 11 + 111** or **123**.

Comment: it is 
1+11+111...
now i got the answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        String n = in.nextLine();
        if (n.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            System.out.println(n + " + " + n + n + " + " + n + n + n + " = "
                    + (Integer.parseInt(n) + Integer.parseInt(n + n) + Integer.parseInt(n + n + n)));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample run-1:**

```
Input number: 5
5 + 55 + 555 = 615
```

**Sample run-2:**

```
Input number: 1
1 + 11 + 111 = 123
```

**Sample run-3:**

```
Input number: a
Error: invalid input.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code blocks as code.

if you want to print the same value twice like if

```
int n = 5;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(n) + "+" + String.valueOf(n) + String.valueOf(n);
```

this would print 5 + 55

```
if you want to print the double of n then:
System.out.println(String.valueOf(n) + " + " + n*2;
```

which would print 5 + 10

but im not sure what you expect your result to be

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help

```
n = in .nextInt();
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
         System.out.print("n");
    }
if(i!=n) {
    System.out.print("+");
}
}
```

Output ::

```
if input =3
Output => n+nn+nnn

if input=5
output => n+nn+nnn+nnnn+nnnnn
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the pattern of n+nn+nnn, you can probably consider the below code

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input number: ");
String n = in.nextLine();
String output = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
 output += Stream.generate(() -> "" + n).limit(i).collect(Collectors.joining()) + "+";
}
System.out.println(output.substring(0, output.length() - 1));
```

Output:

```
Input number: 5
5+55+555
```

Comment: Hey, if you're going to use streams, use it all the way, i.e. replace that old `for` loop with an `IntStream` (and don't use `forEach()`, that would be a failure).

Comment: Yes, that can be also used instead of for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type your number : ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        String x=String.valueOf(n);
        System.out.println(x+ " + "+ x+x +" + " +x+x+x+ " = "+ ((Integer.parseInt(x))+(Integer.parseInt(x+x))+ (Integer.parseInt(x+x+x))));

    }
}
```

Output : (Example for number = 5)

```
Type your number : 5

5 + 55 + 555 = 615
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is yet another alternative with a slight twist.

- `n`, the digit to repeat
- `k`, the number of repetitions.
- called with `successiveSum(n,k)`

```
successiveSum(1,3);
successiveSum(5,3);
successiveSum(1,4);
```

Prints

```
1 + 11 + 111  = 123
5 + 55 + 555  = 615
1 + 11 + 111 + 1111  = 1234
```

The method.

It works by simply building up the number by multiplying by 10 and then adding n.

```
public static void successiveSum(int n, int k) {
   int sum = 0;
   int nextNumb = 0;
   String s = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
       nextNumb = nextNumb * 10 + n;
       s = s + nextNumb + " + ";
       sum += nextNumb;
   }
   // remove the last "+ " of the string.
   System.out.println(s.substring(0,s.length()-2) + " = " + sum);
}
```